# I have a new set of picklist values based on the record types of a custom object. How do I enable them 'selected' by default when the org is upgraded?

Tags: apex, picklist

I have a new set of picklist values based on the record types of a custom object. How do I enable them 'selected' by default when the managed org's package is upgraded? These new set of picklist values are also in the master picklist.

My custom object has different sets of picklist values depending on the record type.

When I upgrade an org and add a picklist value, they don't get "selected by default" and needed to be manually added to the picklist values.

How do I make them selected without going through the UI manually?

[image: RecordType-PicklistValue-DontGetSelectedByDefaultOnOrgUpgrade]

[image: picklist values were added via xml]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! When you say "upgrade an org", what do you mean this? Is it a Production refresh or are you using tooling to deploy from local/shared source control?

Comment: Probably it is meant upgraded as newer version of a package is installed @TSmith

Comment: @TSmith, yes kurunve is correct. Upgrade to a newer version of a managed package. We are adding picklist values to certain record types. The picklist values were added via xml. It's a pain to have the support team/installers to go through each record type and manually select and add the available picklists values.

Comment: Are you delivering upgrades via push upgrades? Can you please [edit] your post to flesh out the context?

Comment: Done @DavidReed. No, not push upgrades. Clients get the package and upgrade their own orgs.

Comment: If you add pick list values to master pick list it doesn’t automatically get added to the record type. Check [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_recordtype_considerations.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: Hi @apple123 thanks for the link, yes I saw that but it's not the issue I'm encountering. The picklist values are already added to the master picklist and also added to the record type via package deployment / upgrade (no user interface manual intervention). However, the new picklist values are not being shown as selected in the record type.

Comment: Are the profiles given access to it from your package?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades will not update certain types of settings, including page layout configurations and record type settings. This is because it may cause unexpected changes in the subscriber's organization. You should include the upgrade steps as a manual post-install step for subscribers moving between the old version and the new. Of course, you could automate it a bit with a [metadata wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), but you'll still need to provide a page for them to upgrade with.